# Is there an easy way to match values of a list to array in R?

Tags: arrays, r, list, combinations

I have several (named) vectors in a list:

```
data = list(a=runif(n = 50, min = 1, max = 10), b=runif(n = 50, min = 1, max = 10), c=runif(n = 50, min = 1, max = 10), d=runif(n = 50, min = 1, max = 10))
```

I want to play around with different combinations of them depending on what an array tells me, for example I want to sum across the different combinations in combs:

```
 var <- letters[1:length(data)]
 combs <- do.call(expand.grid, lapply(var, function(x) c("", x)))[-1,]
```

And get the sums for each row of these combinations. So the results for the first 8 rows would look like this:

```
 res = rbind(a=sum(data[["a"]]), b=sum(data[["b"]]), ab = sum(c(data[["a"]], data[["b"]])), c = sum(data[["c"]]), ac = sum(c(data[["a"]], data[["c"]])), bc = sum(c(data[["b"]], data[["c"]])), abc = sum(c(data[["a"]], data[["b"]], data[["c"]])), d=sum(data[["d"]]))
```

I think it is possible by extracting the list of data, by looping through each rows and each columns (I would have a variable number of columns though), but this seems quite clunky and slow, is there a better way that I am not seeing?

Thanks so much!
Fra

Comment: You can get pretty close using `combn` - like `combn(var, 2, function(x) sum(unlist(data[x])) )` for instance.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I am still not getting each row with combinations... for example row 6 of combs, sum of "bc"... I would like to extract each row of combs...

Comment: `apply(combs, 1, function(x) sum(unlist(data[unlist(x)])) )` maybe?

Comment: YES!!! That's exactly what I have been trying to do!! Thank you!!!

Comment: Hi, on a second thought, I need more operations not only sum, and some require the extraction of individual rows, e.g. using row 8 with the values of a,b,c do some operations. I can't seem to work it out with this, since when I try the apply(combs, 1, function(x) unlist(data[unlist(x)])), I get all the values of a,b,c in series a1,a2...b1,b2... while I need them in vectors of a1,b1,c1; a2,b2... maybe I need to open a new question then...

Comment: maybe mapply and fill with 0 if there are no nchar in combs (is this even possible?)

Comment: Might be worth a new question