# Is there an easy way to extract specific combinations of values from a list?

Tags: r, list, combinations

I have several (named) vectors in a list:

```
data = list(a=runif(n = 50, min = 1, max = 10), b=runif(n = 50, min = 1, max = 10), c=runif(n = 50, min = 1, max = 10), d=runif(n = 50, min = 1, max = 10))
```

I want to play around with different combinations of them depending on the row from another array called combs:

```
 var <- letters[1:length(data)]
 combs <- do.call(expand.grid, lapply(var, function(x) c("", x)))[-1,]
```

I would like to be able to extract each combination so that I can use the vectors created by these combinations.
All this is to be able to apply functions to each row extracted, and then to each combinations of these dataframes. So for example:

```
 # Row 5 is "a", "c"
 combs[5,] 
 # Use this information to extract this particular combination from my data:
 # by hand it would be:
 res_row5 = cbind(data[["a"]], data[["c"]])
 # Extract another combination
 # Row 11 is "a", "b", "d"
 combs[11,] 
 res_row11 = cbind(data[["a"]], data[["b"]], data[["d"]])
 # So that I can apply functions to each row across all these vectors
 res_row_5_func = apply(res_row5, 1, sum)
 # Apply another function to res_row11
 res_row_5_func = apply(res_row11, 1, prod)
 # Multiply the two, do other computations which can do as long as I have extracted the right vectors
```

I had already asked a very similar question here: [Is there an easy way to match values of a list to array in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42967528/is-there-an-easy-way-to-match-values-of-a-list-to-array-in-r?noredirect=1#comment73071850_42967528)

But can't figure out how to extract the actual data...
Thanks so much!

Comment: Is this what you want `as.data.frame(data)[combs[, 5]]` or data[combs[, 5]]? I would use a `data.frame` instead of a `list` as vectors in your data have equal length.

Comment: Not clear to me. Could you update your post with final desired output?

Comment: thank you for your help... The reason I think a list is more appropriate is that I am storing different information in each that I would like to extract by name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is first generate a list of vectors indexing the relevant entries in `data`:

```
library(magrittr)
combList <- lapply(1:nrow(combs), function(ii) combs[ii,] %>% unlist %>% setdiff(""))
```

You could then use this list to index the columns in `data` and generate a new list of the desired matrices:

```
dataMatrixList <- lapply(combList, function(indVec) data[indVec] %>% do.call('cbind', .))
```

The i-th entry in your `dataMatrixList` the contains a matrix with columns corresponding to the i-th row in `combs`. You can then compute sums, products etc. using

```
rowSumsList <- lapply(dataMatrixList, function(x) apply(x, 1, sum))
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be another approach, that I think gives what you want? it will return a list of your dataframes by subsetting your data list by the (non-empty) elements of each row of combs:

```
data_sets <- apply(combs,
    1, 
    function(x) do.call(cbind.data.frame, data[unlist(x[x!=''])])
    )
```

Comment: Thanks so much for both answers!! They give the same solution but this is actually better for what I am doing because I would like to avoid packages...